# How to change default port for T-SQL Debugger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, configuration, debugging

The default port for T-SQL Debugger is 135, it is possible to change this port ? In my company this port is on special list of banned ports, therefore we need to open that service on another port number.

I am following this article:

[Transact-SQL Debugger for SQL Server 2008 – Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/billramo/archive/2009/04/11/transact-sql-debugger-for-sql-server-2008-part-2.aspx) by Bill Ramos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change the TCP port used by T-SQL Debugger.
You can use an application such as [RelayTCP](http://www.dlcsistemas.com/html/relay_tcp.html) and port forwarding rules on your router to achieve what you want. It's difficult to give specific recommendations without knowing more about your network topology.

It may be easier to set up a VPN to your site and then run T-SQL Debugger over VPN (I assume that LAN-local connections to TCP 135 will not be blocked).